# i am not able to update the record using update function into the database using php and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

Here is my table code:

```
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="tabdata in tabledata">
                <td>
                    <div ng-hide="editdata[tabdata.id]">{{tabdata.name}}</div>
                    <div ng-show="editdata[tabdata.id]"><input type="text" ng-model="tabdata.name"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div ng-hide="editdata[tabdata.id]">{{tabdata.city}}</div>
                    <div ng-show="editdata[tabdata.id]"><input type="text" ng-model="tabdata.city"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button ng-hide="editdata[tabdata.id]" ng-click="edit(tabdata)">EDIT</button>
                    <button ng-show="editdata[tabdata.id]" ng-click="update(tabdata)">UPDATE</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here is my code:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
```

Here I get the data from database table:

```
    $http.get('fetch.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.tabledata = data;
    });


    $scope.editdata={};
```

This function is for edit button:

```
    $scope.edit=function(tabdata){
        $scope.editdata[tabdata.id]=true;
    };
```

This is for update button:

```
    $scope.update=function(tabdata) {

        $scope.editdata[tabdata.id] = false;
```

Here i have to call ajax method to update the values into database.
Or we can use service function also?

and i had use orm file for the connectivity of database using $input in my fetch.php file..

```
        $http({
            method:"post",
            url:'fatch.php',
            data:{

            }
        })
    };
}]);
```

The problem is that when i click on edit button it will get modified but after that, when I edit some row data it updates the data in static page only. And I have to update my database table too. So how to do it?

I have to update my database table using SERVICE function and AJAX call method. Any idea how too do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your case:

```
$scope.update=function(tabdata) {

    $scope.editdata[tabdata.id] = false;
    $http({
        method:"post",
        url:'fetch.php',
        data:{
               // your data to send
        }
    }).then(function(success){
        // refresh live your tabledata angularjs will do the job for you
        $http.get('fetch.php').success(function(data) {
            $scope.tabledata = data;
        });
    })
}
```

You don't need Ajax call in your case.

Comment: oops I let "fatch.php" and your where saying that it was "fetch.php" ;)

Comment: so what to do now sir..when i click on update button it will get upadated. but i have to update my database table aslo..how to do it?

Comment: your $http method post will push some data to your service and then inside your fetch.php you'll update your database.